# Pandas select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below `json` string loaded to `dataframe`. Now I want to filter the record based on `ossId`.

The condition I have is giving the error message. what is the correct way to filter by ossId?

```
import pandas as pd

data = """
{
  "components": [
    {
      "ossId": 3946,
      "project": "OALX",
      "licenses": [
        {
          "name": "BSD 3",
          "status": "APPROVED"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ossId": 3946,
      "project": "OALX",
      "version": "OALX.client.ALL",
      "licenses": [
        {
          "name": "GNU Lesser General Public License v2.1 or later",
          "status": "APPROVED"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ossId": 2550,
      "project": "OALX",
      "version": "OALX.webservice.ALL" ,
      "licenses": [
        {
          "name": "MIT License",
          "status": "APPROVED"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"""

df = pd.read_json(data)
print(df)

df1 = df[df["components"]["ossId"] == 2550]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is due to the json structure. You are actually loading into `df` a single row that is the whole list of field `component`.

You should instead pass to the dataframe the list of records. Something like:

```
json_data = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data["components"])

filtered_data = df[df["ossId"] == 2550]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the cell's data and get the correct key:

```
df[df['components'].apply(lambda x: x.get('ossId')==2550)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str`

```
df[df.components.str['ossId']==2550]
Out[89]: 
                                          components
2  {'ossId': 2550, 'project': 'OALX', 'version': ...
```